# How to put an image inside a section?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a small website for a study project but I got a bit blocked

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #161616;
}

section .circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e51e2a;
  clip-path: circle(70% at right -20%);
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header .logo {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="circle">
    <header>
      <a href="#"><img src="images/59-593607_coca-cola-logo-white-png-coca-cola.png" class="logo"></a>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  </div>
</section>
```

.
Anyway, I have been trying for a while to put the logo of my website inside a section but the logo does not appear.
What is the error?

Here's what's going on:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put the logo inside the `.circle` which is the red part. Your logo is on the left side, whereas the red part ends before it.

[image]

You have to remove the circle as a container.

I have done some changes in the format of `HTML`. And also some minor changes in the `CSS`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #161616;
  z-index: 10;
}

section .circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #e51e2a;
  clip-path: circle(70% at right -20%);
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}

header .logo {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 150px;
}

ul {
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<section>
  <header>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA8hF.png" class="logo" />
    </a>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this.

```
<section>
      <header>
        <div class="brand"> 
          <a href="#">
            <img src="https://dcstatic.com/images/brandcrowd/logos/brandcrowd-logo-5d59400c52.svg" class="logo" />
          </a>
       </div>
        <ul class="navigation">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">What's New</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </header>
    </section>
```